# Ubuntu DualBoot Installation Process - Resizing Partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows, partitioning, swap, resize

I decided to have Ubuntu to dualboot with Win7.
I have read couple of guides, and it seems that I still can't get this right.

ATM I have my laptop running the Ubuntu CD, I picked in *installation type* - "Something Else"
and I have 3 Partitions (on the same HD):

1. The 100MB for windows
2. 60GB of Windows
3. 458GB of Data

I want to resize the Data partition to 424GB,
 so I will have 24GB for Ubuntu(20GB) + Swap(4GB).

I pick the 458GB partition and click change, and is says 
"New partition size in megabytes *textbox*"

Now what am I supposed to do so it'll be 20GB for Ubuntu and 4GB Swap?
This

1) One time write "20000" and then *change* again and write "4000"

or

2) Write "424000" to have unallocated space of 24GB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just resize your data partition and create 2 new ones in the now empty space.

You should see something like "extended partition", because you can only have 4 primary partitions. So you usually have one of these extended partitions with some virtual partitions in it.

If repartitioning during installation is too tedious, you can boot from the Ubuntu CD and use "GParted", the partition editor, to do it before.

Good luck! ;)

Comment: Now that I noticed - won't the Ubuntu partition be Logical? I already have 3 primary partitions, so to have swap + root I need two more partitions, which forces me to make the last partition an extended one -> root will be on a logical partition -> only primary partitions are bootable... What do I do?

Comment: That's not an issue. Grub can boot your OS from a logical partition. So if you intend to use Grub and install its Stage 1 into the MBR (thats the standard way of doing it), it will work.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to erase your partitions? if not then I have to tell you that by doing this you will erase all data ...
I recommend you resize your partitions using some tools other than ubuntu installer. try `paragon partition manager`

Comment: Hmmm. If I got to *Try Ubuntu*, can I use GParted to resize and then install?

Comment: I was not lucky with that ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install ubuntu parallely then you will have to delete one of the partition which in this case is DATA (as u told).

But there is one more way which will save you from this all heck of partitioning and all. Use "***wubi***" tool to install Ubuntu inside Windows. Using it you can install Ubuntu very eaisly and it will run as you have installed it side by side.

Comment: From what I have read, Wubi isn't so good... I prefer to have Ubuntu on a different partition, thus, find a way to overcome this problem...